# Determining percentages of shape layer in each grid cell using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

We have five different shape layers (water, forest, ...) for a certain area (which is supposed to be a square about ~50 sq km). What we need is to put something like a grid over our shape layers (each cell = 1 sqm). Then, we would like to know the percentage of each shape layer for every grid cell.

We are using ArcGIS Pro.

It would be also great to put the results into a PMG file or similar so that we have a grid as a layer where each cell has a color that represents the percentage of a layer (for example: a grid cell with five different colors for the cells, presenting the percentage of water).

Answer (score 1):

If you have an advanced licence, the [Tabulate Intersection](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/tabulate-intersection.htm) tool should do exactly what you want. I'd give a read up on it. Although, you say you have your types as different feature classes. You may have to do some sort of merge on these layers before you could run this tool.

If you do not have an advanced license, you can do the workflow manually using the Make Feature Layer tool (making sure to set a ratio policy) and intersect and possibly a statistics of calculation operation.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot!! Does anyone happen to know if it is possible to categorize the percentages and assign them to colors, so every grid cell gets a color according to the category? We need it for a simulation program as a base, however, we are still not sure what the best way is.